# Tipos incompletos y punteros opacos

Tags: c

He visto artículos en ingles que hablan sobre esto, según he logrado entender se usan para encapsulación en C. Alguien puede explicar que es exactamente un tipo incompleto y un puntero opaco? Y cuales usos tienen en C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un típo incompleto es como su nombre lo indica, un típo sin definición, lo que es complementado con los punteros opacos, consideremos el siguiente ejemplo:

#### `fecha.h`

```
typedef struct date date_t;
unsigned get_hours(date_t *dt);

//... Resto de funcionalidades
```

#### `fecha.c`

```
typedef struct date {
    // implementación de la estructura.
} date_t;
```

Tienes una implementación opaca al proveer sólo la declaración de la estructura de datos `date_t`, permitiendo al usuario de tu librería sólo un puntero a la estructura y un conjunto de funciones para darle comportamiento.

Todo se define en el archivo de código que será compilado para entregar el binario a quién lo use.

Estas implementaciones se utilizan para mantener el código lo más oculto posible frente a los usuarios finales, de esta forma no saben el contenido del puntero internamente.

Al final:

- Puntero opaco: Es un puntero a una estructura que desconocemos (4 u 8 bytes) que no sabemos lo que contienen ni su tamaño real.
- Típo incompleto: Típo que sólo ha sido declarado pero no definido frente a los ojos del usuario final.

Un ejemplo práctico:

```
/* date_t.h */
#ifndef DATE_T_HEADER
#define DATE_T_HEADER

/* declaración opaca */
typedef struct date date_t;

/* algunos métodos */
date_t *new_date(void);
unsigned get_hours(date_t *dt);
void set_hours(date_t *dt, unsigned t);
unsigned get_difference_seconds(date_t *dt1, date_t *dt2);
void delete_date(date_t *dt);

#endif /* DATE_T_HEADER */

/* date_t.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "date_t.h"

/* Definición de la estructura */
typedef struct date {
    size_t time;
    char holamundo;
} date_t; /* FAIL PADDING, sizeof esta estructura es 16 u 8 ... */

date_t *new_date(void) {
    date_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    return ptr;
}
unsigned get_hours(date_t *dt) {
    if (dt) return dt->time;
    return 0;
}
void set_hours(date_t *dt, unsigned t) {
    if (dt) dt->time = t;
}
unsigned get_difference_seconds(date_t *dt1, date_t *dt2) {
    if (dt1 && dt2) return dt1->time - dt2->time;
    return 0;
}
void delete_date(date_t *dt) {
    if (dt) { 
        free(dt); 
        dt = NULL;
    }
}

/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "date_t.h"

int main(void) {
    date_t *ptrdate = new_date();
    printf("Nueva fecha\nAjustando a 55 las horas...\n");
    set_hours(ptrdate, 55);
    if (get_hours(ptrdate) == 55)
        printf("En efecto es 55.\n");
    date_t *se = new_date();
    printf("Creada nueva fecha...\n");
    set_hours(se, 10);
    printf("Diferencias: %u\n", get_difference_seconds(ptrdate, se));
    delete_date(ptrdate); delete_date(se);
}
```

Notese que ha sido de cabeza por lo que puede no funcionar del todo *(Pendiente hasta que encuentre mi ordenador)*.

Probar con la siguiente línea de comandos para obtener resultado:

```
> gcc -o date.o -c -std=c11 date.c 
> gcc -o test.o -c -std=c11 test.c
> gcc -o test *.o
```

Debe arrojar el siguiente resultado:

```
Nueva fecha
Ajustando a 55 las horas...
En efecto es 55.
Creada nueva fecha...
Diferencias: 45
```

*SN<sup>1</sup>: `-std=c11` porque nunca hay que perder el estilo.*

Para finalizar, las principales ventajas de implementar este tipo de opacidad en C es que limitas la cantidad de cambios que los usuarios son capaces de hacerle a tu estructura, lo cual tiene un efecto colateral, dado que no todos quieren hacer las cosas a *tu* manera, pero la implementacion es util a la hora de realizar software para vender.

Y como todo en C, no es bueno abusar de este tipo de metodologia.

<sup>1</sup>: Side note.